A way to bring window to the front by just hovering over it?
I recently purchased a 32" 4K monitor for my laptop, and I now have a lot of screen real estate. However, my desktop has become cluttered with many overlapping windows, like this:

I am aware of tools like PowerToys FancyZones for organizing windows and the Alt/Win + Tab shortcuts for switching between them. However, I’m looking for a way to simply hover over a visible portion of a window and bring it to the front without clicking on it — for example, by pressing some (hot)key.
Reason: The visible part of the window often contains interface elements for interaction, but I don’t want to interact with those elements. I just want to bring the window to the front without any additional actions, except hovering over the needed window and pressing some hotkey (e.g., Ctrl), so I would not interact with anything in that window.
Is there a way to achieve this using a PowerToy, an app, registry tweaks, or something else? (Windows 11, if that matters)

Please note that requests that we recommend software products or solutions are explicitly off topic on this site. Please read the HELP section to understand this better. You should EDIT your post to remove that specific request, and to instead focus on asking for help to solve your problem/accomplish what you want. If software IS a solution, that's fine, but make your request about your actual problem. Don't forget to edit the Title as well. You are getting close votes for this reason.

@music2myear Sry I’m pretty new here, so thank you for your advice as a 13-year experienced user. However, I’ve checked the HELP section and didn’t find any prohibition against asking questions about software. On the contrary, it explicitly states: "If you have a question about computer software, then you’re in the right place." (Help center > Asking > What topics can I ask about here?) Could you please clarify which specific HELP article and paragraph you are referring to when stating that asking about software products or solutions is off-topic on this site?

I didn't say software is off topic. I said that specifically asking for a software tool is off topic.

You can ask for software tools on Software Recommendations site.


I am looking for a solution that allows me to simply hover over a visible portion of a window and bring it to the front without having to click on it.

The built-in "Window tracking" or "Focus follows mouse" feature meets that particular requirement, although it doesn't involve a key press (it uses a hover delay).
Windows has had it internally for a long time but doesn't have a GUI for enabling it – back in the Windows 95 days the UI was available as the "Xmouse" PowerToy, current versions don't but you can use the Xmouse Controls app or manually enable it through Registry.

there is a way to activate a window by hovering over it with mouse pointer without using third-party apps:
1> Open Control Panel by searching for it in the Start menu.
2> Click on "Ease of Access Center" icon.
3> Click on "Make the mouse easier to use" link.
4> In the "Make it easier to manage windows" section, check box labeled "Activate a window by hovering over it with the mouse."
5> Click "Apply" then "OK" to save the changes.
6> Now, when you move your mouse pointer over an open window, it will get activated without requiring a click. when you want to disable it, simply uncheck the box from the same setting.
